# Function callback after animation ends in Angular 2

Tags: animation, angular

Using this as my learning source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Do any of you guys know if/how I can call a function once the animation is complete?

I'm creating a To Do app and would like to animate the task fading away when the user hits complete.

I just don't know how to delete it from the array that I store it in after the animation completes. Right now it completely removes it, if I delete it from the array.

If I don't delete it from the array it fades away like expected but it's still in the DOM, just opacity is set to 0.

Having a hard time with google as there doesn't seem to be many animation examples online yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some code example of what you do?
Did you try to work with leave animation: `* => void` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now Angular2 supported `(@animation.start)` and `(@animation.done)` to tap into animation events. You can find out more details about Animation callbacks at [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#animation-callbacks).

Hope this help!